# Android Navigation Drawer nested activity vs fragment approach

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer

first, I'd like to state that I'm new  to android development and to gradle as well. not to java.
I had a project supporting 2.3.6 and I'm now in the process of migrating it to 4.4 using the support library.
I'm using Gradle as well, and so far, it's working great.

I'm now using the navigation drawer to navigate between the app's fragments, which used to be activities.
One of the fragments in the drawer holds a listview and a detail view for an item in the list.
The drawer fragment switches it's view when the user clicks an item in the list and shows it's details.

While it's pretty clear to me why it's not recommended for 2 fragments to communicate directly, I still need the list fragment to tell it's details fragment counterpart about the selected item.
The guides specifically say that the activity should implement the callbacks and on the callback methods it should communicate the data between the fragments.
However, in my case, the parent is also a fragment. 
My question is should the parent fragment maintain the callbacks? 
It seems like the proper solution, since my fragment is only implemented this way to use the navigation drawer swap, and logically, it behaves like an activity, but this would go against the guides saying fragments should not communicate directly.

The question is if implementing the callbacks in the containing fragment is a viable approach or i should change this part of the app to an activity?

Thanks, and sorry for the wall of text.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent fragment should be swapped in via the NavigationDrawerFragment whose callbacks should be implemented in the Activity. The callbacks shouldn't have anything to do with the data passing if I'm understanding you correctly.  If the detail is a child of the parent fragment I don't see any reason that the data can't be passed when the child is created.